# My code wont read my CSV file into the my object list

Tags: c#

Either my CSV file is not being read properly or i'm adding my object to the list wrong but i'm not getting any values added into my list.

I've tried using different paths to my CSV file and I have tried using different ways to read a CSV file but nothing has worked.

```
void TheDex()
{
    List<Class1> Pokedex = new List<Class1>();

    TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("pokemon.csv");
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters(",");

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        string row = parser.ReadLine();
        String[] Columns = row.Split(Convert.ToChar(","));
        Class1 Dex = new Class1();

        Dex.DexNumber = Columns[0];
        Dex.Name = Columns[1];
        Dex.Type1 = Columns[2];
        Dex.Type2 = Columns[3];
        Dex.Total = Columns[4];
        Dex.HP = Columns[5];
        Dex.ATK = Columns[6];
        Dex.DEf = Columns[7];
        Dex.SpAtk = Columns[8];
        Dex.SpDef = Columns[9];
        Dex.Spd = Columns[10];
        Dex.Generation = Columns[11];
        Dex.Legendary = Columns[12];
        Pokedex.Add(Dex);
    }

    parser.Close();
}
```

I want the list Pokedex to contain my objects that hold the data from the CSV but so far the Pokedex list stays empty.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the data that you're trying to read, as well as the definition of Class1, and any exceptions that you're getting?

Comment: What does it look like when you debug this? Is you columns array populated the way you want? Do you see all the properties of you Dex object the way you expect? Do you see your Pokedex list growing? You do know that the list is a local variable of the function, it doesn't live beyond the execution of `TheDex()`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `TextFieldParser` class incorrectly.
After you have initialized the `parser` you can use the `ReadFields` method to get all the fields. It will do this using the delimiters you have specified:

```
List<Class1> Pokedex = new List<Class1>();

string[] delimiters = { "," };
using (TextFieldParser parser = FileSystem.OpenTextFieldParser("Names.txt", delimiters))
{
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

        // populate your class here
        Class1 Dex = new Class1();

        Dex.DexNumber = fields[0];
        Dex.Name = fields[1];

        // add the other fields here


       Pokedex.Add(Dex);
    }
}
```

There are lots of examples of the correct way to use `TextFieldParser` on the internet. I found [this one](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2017/02/use-a-textfieldparser-to-read-delimited-data-in-c/) that shows the example above.

Andy by wrapping the `TextFieldParser` in a `using` clause you don't need to close the parser once you have finished as the `using` statement will handle that for you.

Comment: Thank you very much this fixed the issue I was having.

Comment: Great. Don’t forget to mark the answer as correct so others can find it as well 